# Why is Padding/Margin-bottom Not Working On Image?

Tags: html, css, sass, padding, margin

What i am trying to achieve is to get the image in `div` "dimg2" to be on the same line as the `h3` element.
i have tried block and inline-block display option on both the img and the div its wrapped around in. I have tried `padding/margin` bottom and nothing works. I'm just trying to move the image up. It goes down with `padding-top` but wont go up with `padding-bottom`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

h4 {
  padding-left: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul li {
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #5AB7FF;
  border: 1px solid #5AB7FF;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #5AB7FF;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.fheader {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.img2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}

.dimg2 {
  padding-left: 610px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="./resources/images/wave.png" alt="wave">
  <h4 style="color: #5AB7FF;">Fusion.</h4>
  <ul>
    <li style="color: #5AB7FF;">Home</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Team</li>
    <li>Pricing</li>
    <li>Testimonial</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</header>

<section>
  <div class="fheader">
    <div class="fcontent">
      <h3>App, Business&Saas Landing Page Template</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
         Quisque viverra ligula nunc, ut<br>
         lacinia neque tincidunt at.
         Integer congue hendrerit elit, quis feugiat enim tristique.<br>
         Pellentesque nec urna nisi.
      </p>
      <button class="btn">Download</button> <button class="btn2">Learn More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dimg2">
      <img class="img2" src="./resources/images/app.png" alt="building an app">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically trying to get it to look like this:

[image: Expected Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FUSION</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="./resources/images/wave.png" alt="wave">
            <h4 style= "color: #5AB7FF;">Fusion.</h4>
            <ul>
                <li style= "color: #5AB7FF;">Home</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Team</li>
                <li>Pricing</li>
                <li>Testimonial</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <section>
            <div class="fheader">
                <div class="fcontent">
                    <div class="dimg2">
                        <img class="img2" src="./resources/images/app.png" alt="building an app">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>App, Business&Saas Landing Page Template</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra ligula nunc, ut <br> lacinia neque tincidunt at. Integer congue hendrerit elit, quis feugiat enim tristique <br>. Pellentesque nec urna nisi. 
                </p>
                <button class="btn">Download</button> 
                <button class="btn2">Learn More</button>
             </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>

html, body {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

h4 {
    padding-left: 3px;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul li {
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #5AB7FF;
    border: 1px solid #5AB7FF;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 25%;
    padding: 15px;

}

.btn2 {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #5AB7FF;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 25%;
    padding: 15px;

}

.fheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.img2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.dimg2 {
    float: right;
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Reposition the image above h3 tag in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try using position absolute on one of them and change its position from itself ...
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check  usage of Div, p and h3 element.
Div,p and h3 all display content in blocks and if you want to have your image on the same line then you have to make it in grid.
I would suggest use bootstarp for grid.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

The fcontent class is not "inline block" yet, and doesn't have a width property, making it automatically 100% of it's parent (fheader) and leaving no room for the dimg2.
If you fix this you don't need padding on the dimg2 anymore.
replace:

```
      .img2 {
          width: 500px;
          height: 500px;
          margin-bottom: 400px;
      }

      .dimg2 {
          position: absolute;
          display: inline-block;
      }
      .fcontent{
        width:50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top:0px;
      }
```